# Machine learning models: should I define a class or function

Tags: python, machine-learning

I'm using Python to write my own machine learning models for practice. There are two ways I can go about it:

1. Write a function e.g. `def logisticRegression(...):`
2. Write a class e.g. `class logisticRegression:`

Obviously, both will work. But which is more Pythonic?

Comment: either,  but to be 'pythonic' use `def logistic_regression` or `class LogisticRegression`

Comment: This is unfortunately off-topic, as there is no clear definite right answer here and is subject to opinion, as there are several factors to take in to account. The design approach for a learning model would probably require some thought and have class structures to help architect a more readable maintainable solution. Also, as already mentioned in the comment above, naming style is part of being *pythonic*, so you should look at the [Style Guide](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)

Comment: Furthermore, here is an explanation of [what is Pythonic](http://blog.startifact.com/posts/older/what-is-pythonic.html). Also, open your interpreter and type `import this`. Read that too. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For me it makes more sense to go with a class approach as you can save your model as instance of the class and have as class functions something like a `train()` to initialize the model and a `predict()` method to use your model multiple times without having to retrain it.

Look at the [scikit-learn class for Logistic Regression](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.html#sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression), it makes a lot of sense and is very intuitive.

Comment: worth noting that when dealing with some libraries, class based approach might be problematic. In particular tensorflow goes rather with functional approach (due to specifics of graph-based-computations paradigm)